# Extract the output of the embedding layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, categorical-data, embedding

I am trying to build a regression model, for which I have a nominal variable with very high cardinality. I am trying to get the categorical embedding of the column.

Input:

```
df["nominal_column"]
```

Output:

```
the embeddings of the column.
```

I want to use the op of the embedding column alone since I would require that as a input to my traditional regression model. Is there a way to extract that output alone.

P.S I am not asking for code, any suggestion on the approach would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the embedding is part of the model and you train it, then you can use functional API of keras to get output of any intermediate operation in your graph:

```
x=Input((number_of_categories,))
y=Embedding(parameters_of_your_embeddings)(x)
output=Rest_of_your_model()(y)
model=Model(inputs=[x],outputs=[output,y])
```

if you do it before you train the model, you'll have to define custom loss function, that deals only with part of the output. The other way is to train the model with just one output, then create identical model with two outputs and set the weights of the second model from the trained one.

If you want to get the embedding matrix from your model, you can just use method get_weights of the embedding layer which returns the weights in numpy array.